# Conventional Route Folders only returns root page

Tags: remix, remix.run

I'm just starting with `Remix` and struggling to understand the `Route` system.

Looking at the documentation around [Conventional Route Folders](https://remix.run/docs/en/main/discussion/routes#conventional-route-folders) it seems to me I should be able to create URL structures like the below to create a page like `/test` and also have a page like `/test/dynamic-route` which will provide a `param` value - but Remix will only ever return the root `/test` page (try following this links on this [test page](https://stackblitz.com/edit/remix-run-remix-j3cvog?file=app%2Froutes%2Ftest._index%2Froute.tsx)).

So my questions are:

- Why does it always redirect to the folder root page (`/test`)
- What's the difference between `/test/route.tsx` and `/test._index/route.tsx`? Do I need them both?

As I'm very new to this metaframework I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

[image]

I've created a StackBlitz example of the issue I'm seeing [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/remix-run-remix-j3cvog?file=app%2Froutes%2Ftest._index%2Froute.tsx) - feel free to fork / play!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `test/route.tsx` is the parent layout for all the `test/*` routes. If you want to render your child routes, you need an `<Outlet>` (think of it is the `children` prop).

`test/_index/route.tsx` is the *index* route, and matches the `/test/` URL. The contents will be rendered in the `<Outlet>` from `test/route.tsx`.

If you run `npx remix routes`, you'll see the route structure.

```xml
❯ npx remix routes
<Routes>
  <Route file="root.tsx">
    <Route index file="routes/_index/route.tsx" />
    <Route path="test" file="routes/test/route.tsx">
      <Route path=":paramId" file="routes/test.$paramId/route.tsx" />
      <Route index file="routes/test._index/route.tsx" />
      <Route path="sub" file="routes/test.sub/route.tsx" />
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Here's my fork that fixes the layout.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/remix-run-remix-kl2as5?file=app%2Froutes%2Ftest%2Froute.tsx

Comment: You beauty! Thank you.